# Handling two dropdown select options

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular5

I have two drop down based on that,I am making REST calls and fetching data.
if user select "ALL" in either of them,I am displaying all data,but when user chooses diff option,it will fetch the data based on the options provided.
I am using below calls for html & ts file:

test.component.html:

```
<select (change)="selectHandler($event)">
     <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
     <option value="M1">M1</option>
</select>

<select (change)="selectHandler($event)">
      <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
      <option value="G1">G1</option>
```

.......
   later I am looping to get values like below:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let testcase of selectedGrpMod">
  ....
```

test.component.ts:

```
selectHandler(moduleEvent: any, groupEvent: any) {
    if (moduleEvent.target.value == "ALL" || moduleEvent.target.value == "ALL") {
  this.dataService.getTest().then(res => {this.selectedGrpMod = res;})
   }
   else {
       this.dataService.getTesByParam(groupEvent.target.value, moduleEvent.target.value).then(res => {this.selectedGrpMod = res;})
    }
 }
```

Problem is I am unable to handle both drop down at once,its not picking the correct data,perhaps I am using common selectHandler(..) and able to access dropdown one by one,so its not picking the dropdown value of other dropdown n vice-versa,need help/pointers to use correct logic for this situation.Basically if i select M1 from first dropdown and G1 from second dropdown ,then I have to send both M1 & G1 to my ts file so that I can make API call based on these both values..

Comment: Sorry, I voted negative because nothing about selectedGrpMod is in your html. I don`t see angular any where. I can not imagine how do you try to relationated your .html with your .ts

Comment: added details,please remove downvote n help me to solve it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anad, don't use DOM, use templateDriven form, or Reactive Form or User input https://angular.io/guide/user-input

The most easy, using User Input, I'll use two inputs, change to use two dropdown

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  template: `
    <--!see, we write #box1 and #box2, so
       we can use box1.value and box2.value in our function -->
    <input #box1 (change)="update(box1.value,box2.value)">
    <input #box2 (change)="update(box1.value,box2.value)">
  `
})
export class myComponent {
  update(value1: string,value2:string) {
    console.log(value1,value2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to show data as per both list

1. Take a button like show data which calls function in your UI

**or**

2. Call API on click of option of second list

How to get value in component of both dropdown
1. ViewChild or JavaScript

```
<select>
       <option *ngFor="let option of optionList" 
    value="ALL"  #optionIst>{{option.name}}   
       </option>      
    </select>

     <select>
       <option *ngFor="let option of optionList" 
    value="ALL"  #optionSec>{{option.name}}   
       </option>      
    </select>
<button (click)="showData()">Show Data </button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('optionIst')
optionIst: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('optionSec')
optionSec: ElementRef;


    showData()
    {
     const value1 = this.optionIst.nativeElement.value;
     const value1 = this.optionSec.nativeElement.value;
   //Access both elements here by DOM properties
    }
```

2. Bind both option tag with ngModel

   ```
   <select>
      <option *ngFor="let option of optionList" value="{{option.name}}" [(ngModel)]="optionIst"> {{option.name}}   
          </option>
   ```

Similarly second option and call API on button click.

Comment: Hi Rajat,tahnks for answer,but I need to pass both the selected options from the both dropdown (so i hv to record options from both of them,lets say i got M1 from first dropdown and G1 from second one,then i hv to pass both of this to API))and then construct an API call and display the data based on that api call..m not sure if above code does that...plz correct me if i m wrong

Comment: one more doubt,how to acess both elements as string using DOM:

 showData()
    {
   //Access both elements here by DOM properties
    }

Comment: only problem left is above code is picking always first dropdown values even if i am selecting any other from dropdown